# How to merge rows with consecutive datetime

Tags: r

a question from R newbie user: I have a data with consecutive `enabled_datetime` and `disabled_datetime` as shown below:

```
x<-as.data.frame(cbind(
      supplier_id=281743,
      enabled_datetime=c('2016-06-13 13:31:02','2016-06-14 07:39:19','2016-06-14 12:36:03','2016-06-16 13:44:30','2016-06-17 06:42:14'),
      disabled_datetime = c('2016-06-14 07:39:19','2016-06-14 12:36:03','2016-06-16 13:44:30','2016-06-17 06:42:14',  NA),
      discount=c(25,15,15,10,30))
)
x

supplier_id    enabled_datetime   disabled_datetime discount
      281743 2016-06-13 13:31:02 2016-06-14 07:39:19       25
      281743 2016-06-14 07:39:19 2016-06-14 12:36:03       15
      281743 2016-06-14 12:36:03 2016-06-16 13:44:30       15
      281743 2016-06-16 13:44:30 2016-06-17 06:42:14       10
      281743 2016-06-17 06:42:14                <NA>       30
```

**What I'd like to transform into is like this:**

```
supplier_id    enabled_datetime   disabled_datetime discount
      281743 2016-06-13 13:31:02 2016-06-14 07:39:19       25
      281743 2016-06-14 07:39:19 2016-06-16 13:44:30       15
      281743 2016-06-16 13:44:30 2016-06-17 06:42:14       10
      281743 2016-06-17 06:42:14                <NA>       30
```

i.e. merge rows with the same `supplier_id`, `discount` and have consecutive `enabled_datetime` and `disabled_datetime`. What I can think of is to use `for` loop, any one know how to do so different way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Read about `lead()`, `lag()` and [merge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871).

Comment: why merging  ? group by supplier_id and discount, and arrange the date, you can do this with dplyr ...correct me if i'm wrong ? PS: pls why downvoting like this ?

Comment: @DimitriPetrenko it's not 'merge' in as used in dplyr, what I mean is I want to combine those two rows into one rows. Any idea how to do so (in dplyr is ok)?

Answer (score 2):

```
 df <- data.frame(supplier_id = c(281743,281743,281743,281743,281743),
                 enabled_datetime = c("2016-06-13 13:31:02","2016-06-14 07:39:19","2016-06-14 12:36:03","2016-06-16 13:44:30","2016-06-17 06:42:14"),
                 disabled_datetime = c("2016-06-14 07:39:19","2016-06-14 12:36:03","2016-06-16 13:44:30","2016-06-17 06:42:14",NA),
                 discount = c(25,15,15,10,30))

df <- df%>%
  mutate(enabled_datetime = as.POSIXct(strftime(enabled_datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")),
         disabled_datetime = as.POSIXct(strftime(disabled_datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

subdf1 <- df%>% 
  group_by(supplier_id,discount)  %>%
  mutate(enabled_datetime_lead = lead(enabled_datetime),disabled_datetime_lead = lead(disabled_datetime)) %>%
  filter(disabled_datetime==enabled_datetime_lead) %>% mutate(disabled_datetime = disabled_datetime_lead) %>% 
  select(-enabled_datetime_lead,-disabled_datetime_lead) %>% ungroup()

subdf2<- anti_join(df,resdf,by=c("supplier_id","discount"))

resdf <- full_join(subdf1,subdf2,,by=c("supplier_id","discount"))
```

The result of this is

```
supplier_id    enabled_datetime   disabled_datetime discount
        <dbl>              <time>              <time>    <dbl>
1      281743 2016-06-14 07:39:19 2016-06-16 13:44:30       15
2      281743 2016-06-13 13:31:02 2016-06-14 07:39:19       25
3      281743 2016-06-16 13:44:30 2016-06-17 06:42:14       10
4      281743 2016-06-17 06:42:14                <NA>       30
```

explanation for changes: changed the final statement from `full_join` to `union` as the final result got two new columns. the behaviour is different to what was originally found.

Comment: The solution promtpts errors, and doesn't produce the result as you cited. Shouldn't it be `subdf2<- anti_join(df,resdf,by=c("supplier_id","discount"))`?

Comment: @macchiavalley, what is resdf? I can not find it!